# PHP id in .htaccess

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I Have a .htaccess file for a blog script which currently generates a number for a blog post based on it's ID in the MySQL database. Is there any way I can change this so that it uses something like $subject as the URL from my PHP file? I have pasted my current .htaccess code below.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?act=blog&id=$1`

I hope people can understand what I am trying to describe.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Callum Whyte

Comment: Do you want the subject instead of the id or together with the id in the url?

Comment: @theomega Yes, you are correct. I want the subject instead of the ID in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Using just the subject is probably a bad idea, if you ever change the title, all links to your page (from google, or elswhere) will be broken. I would include both the subject and the idea, that way you'll always be able to match an URL to a blog post:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^blog-[^-]+-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?act=blog&id=$1
```

This should match everything except a - between *blog* and the id.
Now you should be able to call, e.g., *yousite/blog-some_title_or_other-494.html* and it will call *index.php?act=blog&id=494*. This new rule shouldn't break any of your old backlinks either. If it does, let me know and I'll fix it.

Comment: +1 for include the ID. (btw, you'll note that this is how this site works)

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if I can include something like $subject or $date from my PHP file into my URL created by the .htaccess?

Comment: Tomalak: I don't understand?. Callum: Sorry, what do you mean? Isn't that what we just did? :)